# Is OptaPlanner the right tool?

Tags: optimization, workflow, optaplanner

Is it possible to create a real time workflow optimization using OptaPlanner?
Or is there other open source alternative?

The number of workers that are available to each sub station fluctuates with time. So we will only know the number of maximum worker right before the work start.

The diagram below is the possible situation.

[image: Real time finite capacity scheduling]

Comment: Sounds like this might be similar to the [Project Job Scheduling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns) example?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Thanks! Sorry to ask such a simple question. My Java and Android skills are quite limited

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a continuous planning problem like the nurse rostering example on the optaplanner site